# Get div value using jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery

A have `e3` and `e2` divs, and parent div `e`.
There is too many `e` divs on the page.
How can I get `e3` div value when I click on div `e2`?
Thanks.

Comment: What are "e", "e2" and "e3"? Are they classes, IDs (change if they are IDs, because they must be unique), or values of other attributes? What is your markup structure? What value are you intending to fetch? Division elements do not have the `value` attribute.

Comment: This question is nonsensical currently; we have no idea what you mean by `'e2'`, `'e3'` and so forth, we can't see your HTML structure (because you haven't taken the time to show us) therefore we have no means whatsoever of explaining, or showing, how you can "*get 'e3' div value*" after clicking on "*div 'e2'*", because we don't know what it is, or where it is. With that in mind I'm voting to close as 'unclear what you're asking.' Should you edit your question (see: [ask] for guidance) please notify me (with an @davidThomas) and I'll remove my close-vote, if the edit helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `value` attribute for div. You could get the `innerHTML` through javascript.

`var divValue = document.getElementById('e3').innerHTML;`

Answer (score 0):

Let me first tell you how i understood the question. This is kind of how your html is structured:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="e">
  <div id="e2">
    i am e2 text
  </div>
  <div id="e3">
    i am e3 text
  </div>
</div>
<div id="e">
  another e text
</div>
```

And this is the js code that will give the content of the e3 div when the user click on the e2 div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#e2").click(function(){
    alert($("#e3").html());
  })
});
```

Hope this helps :)